# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'project')

Tags: graphql, apollo

I'm working on a Apollo MERN Web. When I'm trying to print the data from GraphQL it shows an undefined error.

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'project')

```
ProjectDetails.jsx?t=1676908708664:34 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'project')
    at ProjecDetails (ProjectDetails.jsx?t=1676908708664:34:51)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom_client.js?v=77af9878:12169:26)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom_client.js?v=77af9878:14919:21)
    at beginWork (react-dom_client.js?v=77af9878:15900:22)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback2 (react-dom_client.js?v=77af9878:3672:22)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom_client.js?v=77af9878:3697:24)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom_client.js?v=77af9878:3731:39)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom_client.js?v=77af9878:19759:15)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom_client.js?v=77af9878:19192:20)
    at workLoopSync (react-dom_client.js?v=77af9878:19131:13)
```

If I add

```
if (loading) return <p>Loading...</p>;
  if (error) return <p>Error</p>;
```

The "Uncaught TypeError:" disaperas but I'm not able to see the data requested from GraphQL.

This is my code

```
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import { useQuery } from "@apollo/client";
import { GET_PROJECT } from "../graphql/projects";

export function ProjecDetails() {
  const params = useParams();
  const { data, loading, error } = useQuery(GET_PROJECT, {
    variables: {
      id: params.id,
    },

  });

  console.log(data)

  if (loading) return <p>Loading...</p>;
  if (error) return <p>Error</p>; 
  
  return <div>

   <h1>{data.project.name}</h1>
    <p>{data.project.description}</p>
    <button>Update</button>

  </div>;
}
```

Here's my Apollo tasks config

```
import { gql } from "@apollo/client";

export const GET_PROJECTS = gql`
  {
    projects {
      _id
      name
      description
    }
  }
`;

export const GET_PROJECT = gql`
  query ($id: ID!) {
    project(_id: $id) {
      _id
      name
      description
      createdAt
      tasks {
        _id
        title
      }
    }
  }
`;

export const CREATE_PROJECT = gql`
  mutation ($name: String, $description: String) {
    createProject(name: $name, description: $description) {
      _id
      name
      description
    }
  }
`;
```

Thank you

**Tried using**

```
skip: !params.id,
```

**Also**

```
if (loading) return <p>Loading...</p>;
  if (error) return <p>Error</p>;
```

But still having same error.

Console.log

```
Download the Apollo DevTools for a better development experience: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/apollo-client-developer-t/jdkknkkbebbapilgoeccciglkfbmbnfm
ProjectDetails.jsx:32 undefined
installHook.js:1608 undefined
ProjectDetails.jsx:32 undefined
installHook.js:1608 undefined
```

Comment: Would you please also post your console log?

Comment: Download the Apollo DevTools for a better development experience: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/apollo-client-developer-t/jdkknkkbebbapilgoeccciglkfbmbnfm
ProjectDetails.jsx:32 undefined
installHook.js:1608 undefined
ProjectDetails.jsx:32 undefined
installHook.js:1608 undefined

Answer (score 0):

Fixed.

By mistake, I named the project single URL with wring ID.